# 'Either or' type of regex in Emacs occur function?

Tags: emacs, elisp

My version of Emacs is 23.0.91.1.  Ubuntu did not catch up with 23.1, yet.  Anyway,

I have an strace capture, and wanted to see file descriptors usage.
So, wanted to see "^(open|socket)" regexp on occur, but didn't work.
Grouping regexp does not work in Emacs regexp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bare parentheses and pipe characters are not metacharacters in Emacs; you need a preceding backslash to make them do grouping and alternation, respectively.  So, you want:

```
^\(open\|socket\)
```